# Using return value of extraction operator in condition?

Tags: c++

Why `ss >> aa >> bb >> cc >> dd` could be used in condition check ? If i use `ss >> aa >> bb >> cc >> dd >> ee` what's the return value of this operation ?

```
ifstream inputFile("source.txt", ifstream::in);
string aa, bb, cc, dd;
char line[1024];

while(!inputFile.eof())
{
    inputFile.getline(line, 1023);
    stringstream ss(stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
    ss.str(line);

    if(ss >> aa >> bb >> cc >> dd)
    {
        cout << aa << "-" << bb << "-" << cc << "-" << dd << endl;
    }
}
```

With **source.txt** like this:

```
1aaa ddd eee asd
2dfs dfsf sdfs fd     
3sdf sdfsdfsdf d s
```

Comment: Note that you're using the results of `inputFile.getline` without checking whether it succeeded or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value of a stream input operation is the stream.

The expression

```
ss >> aa
```

is equal to

```
operator>>(ss, aa)
```

and the `operator>>()` function returns the first argument.

Using multiple input operations simply chains the function calls. For example

```
ss >> aa >> bb;
```

becomes

```
operator>>(ss, aa).operator>>(ss, bb);
```

The *reason* a stream can be use as a boolean expression, is because it has a special [conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) that allows it to be used as such.

---

By the way, you shouldn't use `while (!stream.eof())`. Instead use the fact that `getline` returns the stream, and that a stream can be used in boolean expressions:

```
while (inputFile.getline(line, 1023))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: And it then gets converted to a `void *`, I believe for "is it true or not", and the value is based on the state flags (same as `!good` or something close to that)

Comment: @MatsPetersson Or a `bool` (if using C++11). Just added that. And it's "true" when `fail()` returns `true`.

Comment: @MatsPetersson _Not_ the same as `good()`, but rather `!fail()`.  This is important: `good()` includes the `eofflag` in its evaluation, which makes it useless; `fail()` returns `failbit || badbit`; in other words, it only takes the results of the preceding input into account.